# In bash, is there a way have multiple pipes to one process?

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

For example, if I want to do a `diff` of two files after preprocessing both of them with `sed`, is there any way to do this without temporary files?

I have tried things like this and (as I expected) it did not work:

```
(sed "$expr" file1; sed "$expr" file2) | diff - -
```

I was thinking there might be a way to create pipes explicitly or something.

Comment: If you post your files, we may help you to make one awk command that does everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
diff <(sed "$expr" file1) <(sed "$expr" file2)
```

This uses *Process Substitution*. `<( )` is replaced by a temporary filename. Writing or reading that file causes bytes to get piped to the command inside. Often used in combination with file redirection:

```
cmd1 2> >(cmd2)
```

See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: In `cmd1 <(cmd2)`, how long does the pipe last? Is it closed as soon as `cmd1` exits?

Comment: Good question. In `cmd2 | cmd1`, `cmd2` can continue after `cmd1` exits as long as it doesn't try to write to the closed pipe. Process substitution may work similarly.

Comment: Is there a way that ` sed "$expr"` can be stated only once?